# Countup will be start when reached scroll point in countup div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating one page template. I have create a countup section. I want to display countup animation, when display countup section in screen. That mean, when scroll point reached countup section, animation will be start.

activation script

```
$('.count').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    start:  0,
    end:10,
    duration: 10000
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would watch the window scroll event (debounced for performance) and when the distance from the scroll to your element is < X amount of pixels trigger your animation

```
(function($, window){
    var $window = $(window);
    var $countupSection = $('.countup-section');
    var countupTop = $countupSection.offset().top;

    var debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    var checkPosition = function(){
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if(scrollTop - countupTop < 20){
            //unbind the event so animation triggers only once
            $window.off('scroll', debouncedScroll);
            $('.count').jQuerySimpleCounter({
                start:  0,
                end:10,
                duration: 10000
            });
        }
    };

    var debouncedScroll = debounce(checkPosition, 50);

    $window.on('scroll', debouncedScroll);
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: Hi kevin, it working but i want to stop animation after complete animation one time. Is it posible?

Comment: Updated the code to unbind the scroll event after the animation is triggered once